# Create wordpress website Reader for an iOS device i:e showing notification/Reading content only if the site content/feed is updated

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, api, web-applications

I have an idea to develop iOS App which update user if any feed is updated on wordpress website. Please tell the way/steps how i can achieve the same.

I have tried and searched on google but didn't got solution for my problem. This is one thing i got on youtube about web site reader : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bk0d1npGoq4   But, I doesn't have to developer such app which reads web site content, i would like to show notification as soon as feed on the web is updated.

This is the website ( http://www.webhostingbreak.com/ ) whose reader i want to developer.

Please suggest me some solutions or logic which can help me to complete my task.

Answer (score 0):

You've got several way to access the content of a Wordpress blog.

First and easiest solution is to use the basic RSS feed which is available on any Wordpress, and which is compatible with other kinds of websites.

With Wordpress, more specifically, you can use the XML-RPC API embed by the CMS.
This API need to be enable on the Wordpress website and every request will have to be authenticated with a real user to the Wordpress website (you can implement the registration process in the app or use a generic user in every installed app).

You have several library which handle the XML-RPC calls such as https://github.com/corristo/xmlrpc